# Ubuntu - Sybase - PHP not able to connect

Tags: php, ubuntu, sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere

I'm trying to connect Sybase 17 from PHP(7.4, 8.0) Laravel running on apache2 on Ubuntu(18.4) system. We are using SQL Anywhere. Sybase is not installed on the same server.

> We are getting this error - Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17_r.so' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect in /var/www/html/sybaseconnection.php on line 14

We've already performed the below steps:

1. Already verified libdbodbc17_r.so file is there.
2. Necessary permission is already given.
3. Able to connect using Telnet and command line to SQL Anywhere 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can probably not load the file, since that file has some more dependencies.

I would suggest to do these two things:
Include the content of `/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh` into `/etc/apache2/envvars`

and

Create a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/sqlanywhere17.conf` with this content

```
/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64
/opt/sqlanywhere17/resr
```

Then restart apache and it should be able to connect